# How do I write an exists subquery using multiple columns in LINQ?

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

I am trying to write a linq query that resembles this SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM Table1
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM Table2
    WHERE Table1.ColA = Table2.ColA
    AND Table1.ColB = Table2.ColB
)
```

Except Table2 is an object list I already have previously from the database.

I know how to use contains() to emulate an SQL "IN SUBQUERY" using a object list outside of the database when one column is involved:

```
var query = from t1 in db.Table1
            where MyObjList.Select(o => o.Field1).Contains(t1.Col1)
            select t1;
```

I figure I can do a join in Linq. But will that perform ok? I hope avoid a database call per object in my list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var q = from t1 in db.Table1
        from t2 in db.Table2.Where(x => x.ColA == t1.ColA && x.ColB == t1.ColB)
        select t1;
```

Comment: This does the trick if it is straight SQL. But I was using an existing object list which produced 1 query per object in the collection. Instead I used the 2nd "contains()" example to pull the bigger set (which was one SQL call) and then used the two object lists in a Linq query like yours to filter it further.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
var query = from t1 in db.Table1
            join t2 in db.Table2 on t1.ColA equals t2.ColA
            Where t1.ColB == t2.ColB
            Select t1;
```

OR without Join

```
var query = from t1 in db.Table1
            from t2 in db.Table2 
            Where t1.ColA == t2.ColA && t1.ColB == t2.ColB
            Select t1;
```